# Retain sign and decimal after MSB to LSB swaping

Tags: c++, c, c++11

I am getting data as hex values in 2 byte short values, but after swapping value got lost.

```
 signed short value = 0x0040;
 value = (value*0.5) - 40;
 convertMSBTOLSB(value); //Conversion used bcz my device reading as LSB first

//Implementation of convertMSBTOLSB(value)
unsigned short temp = ((char*) &value)[0];  // assign value's LSB
temp = (temp << 8) | ((char*) &value)[1];   // shift LSB to MSB and add value's MSB
value = temp;
```

After conversion I got value as -8

Problem happened when  I send 0x51, The final value should be 0.5 but getting zero because value is signed short.

convertMSBTOLSB is just  byte swapping, how can I handle the code so that it can parse both -ve and decimal values

Expecting some input to change the code in such away that it can parse both -ve and decimal values

Comment: If you cannot change the type of `value` then how do you expect to store decimals?

Comment: This post's goal really needs more explanation

Answer (score 0):

You won't get 0.5 because your `value` variable is declared short, and therefore can hold only integers.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear. you wrote that convertMSBTOLSB swaps between MSB and LSB, and you also wrote that

> convertMSBTOLSB is just byte swapping

Since MSB and LSB reffering to **Bits** and not to **Bytes** I really dont understand what are you trying to swap here.

Answer (score 0):

Your `value` should change its type. `0.5` and `value` are of incompatible types (integer and float). Therefore, the operation `(value*0.5)` will result in a zero.

Additional to this, 40 will be promoted to a `double` and therefore after assigning this back to `value` then the value will be truncated.

Comment: Detail: 40 will be promoted to a `double`.  `0.5` is `double`, not `float`.

Comment: Correct chux. Thanks for clarifying that.